# cannot get vagrant to work with puppet

Tags: vagrant, puppet

here's the Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/learning/manifests"
  puppet.module_path = "puppet/learning/modules"
  puppet.manifest_file  = "default.pp"
  puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
end
```

I put the puppet folder in the same folder of Vagrantfile

```
/vagrant/
```

here's the puppet command vagrant try to execute.

```
puppet apply --verbose --debug 
             --modulepath '/etc/puppet/modules:/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0' 
             --color=false 
             --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests 
             --detailed-exitcodes /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp || [ $? -eq 2 ]
```

instead get the folder from /vagrant/puppet, it went to /tmp/vagrant-puppet. also I didnt know why it add -0 to module folder "module-0". Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

For the folder, **it's as designed** : the puppet provisioner is supposed to share your local directory puppet/learning/modules (relative to your Vagrantfile) with provisioned vm at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0.

This synch directory is done at vm startup. You may need to do a `vagrant reload` to have your Vagrantfile changes to take effect.

I would encourage you to stick to a more **standard setup**. Take a look at vagrant/puppet project using a more standard layout like this [gareth sample](https://github.com/garethr/riemann-vagrant). It's also using librairian-puppet which also a best practices.